# ERROR Plugin load failed: hexo-deployer-git when I deploy the blog

Tags: node.js, github, hexo

Git, node, hexo are all installed correctly.But when I installed hexo-deployer-git, all the hexo commands will have the following problems. Is this a problem with the plugin? How should I solve it?
The following is an error message, can you help me?

```
        '''
$ hexo d
ERROR Plugin load failed: hexo-deployer-git
D:\blog\node_modules\picomatch\lib\picomatch.js:54
    let ignoreOpts = { ...options, ignore: null, onMatch: null, onResult: null };
                       ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\blog\node_modules\picomatch\index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\blog\node_modules\hexo-deployer-git\node_modules\readdirp\index.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
ERROR Deployer not found: git
        '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be running an older version of Node that doesn't support that syntax.  The SyntaxError is being caused by the spread operator `...`, which is supported in Node versions 8.3 or later.

To check your Node version run `node -v` in a terminal window.

Comment: Thank you. The problem has been solved. You are right.